# "Side by side markdown" span strips new lines from rendering

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, markdown, documentation

The span element contains new lines, but these aren't show. In the main site a table is used, I think that in this case a code tag with the same background-color: rgb(209, 225, 173) and color: rgb(64, 90, 4) of the diff-add class would solve the issue.

[image: How it looks right now]

[image: How it would look]